# Issue with pipe translation

Tags: angular, pipe, translation, nomachine-nx

Project written in Angular from NX.

First I have to say that I can't provide any code because the app is too big and I have no idea which part is wrong.

I have a bug to fix. Throughout the app, the translation works for two languages: English and Polish, but not for Dutch, Spanish and Romanian. Anyone know why this is happening? I only got one clue to check "pluralization", but have no idea where to start?

Comment: how about some stack trace of the error? or specify what is not working? have a look at Angulars ICU and check if you've made a mistake in one of your translation files

Comment: check the json of the different languages and if you did not make a mistake when using variables. we had one string that had a mistake like this {%  mypercentage} but it should be %{mypercentage}